# T4MVC MapRoute doesn't work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

I am trying to setup index page route. It works this way:

```
routes.MapRoute("", "", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"})
```

but if I replace it with T4MVC:

```
routes.MapRoute("", "", MVC.Home.Index());
```

somehow it doesn't work (I get a "The resource can not be found" error). Seems like I did it millions of times and it worked. So what am I doing wrong?

**Update.**

I used Route Debugger and found out the difference between ASP.NET MVC route and T4MVC route is that T4MVC adds Area="" while ASP.NET MVC doesn't (it keeps only controller and action).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused with some problems with assemblybindings. I looked through Warnings in VS, pressed twice on the warning about assemblybindings and they were fixed. This question helped me a lot: [T4MVC ArgumentOutOfRangeException in View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948377/t4mvc-argumentoutofrangeexception-in-view)

Answer (score 1):

Update (7/15/2014): as a workaround, I think you'll need to add a dummy area to your project, e.g.

- Right click Project and choose Add / Area. Name it 'Dummy' (or whatever)
- You can delete everything in there except for the DummyAreaRegistration.cs file

Original answer:

If you 'Go to definition' on your `MapRoute` call, can you check that it indeed goes to a T4MVC overload? Note that if you're in an Area, you'll need to call `MapRouteArea` instead.

Comment: It goes to T4Extensions.cs and I don't use areas

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that MVC.Home.Index() returns ActionResult

if you want to get name of action and controller, you have to write:

MVC.Home.Index().GetT4MVCResult().Controller - name of the Controller
MVC.Home.Index().GetT4MVCResult().Action - name of the Action

Edited:

```
routes.MapRoute("", "", new {controller = MVC.Home.Index().GetT4MVCResult().Controller, action = MVC.Home.Index().GetT4MVCResult().Action})
```

Comment: Why is it "not so good". What if I rename the controller or action?

Comment: I could not be able to find example of where we had problems with areas, but anywhere you can try this. (Probably it was mvc 3 or so, and in mvc 4 and 5 it's already fixed)